# Java 64bit VM - Video frame grab realtime for pixel manipulation

Tags: java, video, jvm, 64-bit, real-time

Authoring a real time VJ application (Chaoslab VJ). Have been using JMF for video playback and frame grabbing.  The resulting grabbed image is just an int array.  It's not bad performance wise and can handle multiple videos being played mixed with effects no problem.

But... JMF is old, has stability issues, not maintained and does not work with a 64bit JVM.  On Windows a 32bit JVM is limited to 1.5g of ram where a 64bit JVM is limited to 8g of ram.

Question:
What is the best current 64bit JVM compatible Java API / Library to use for video playback and frame grabbing (to an int array).

### Update:

JavaCV / OpenCV was the way too go and have got it working.  Feel free to ask if you need a hand grabbing raw pixel data from a video stream in Java.

Tutorial - http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/OpenCV-JavaCV

GitHub - https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Comment: Sorry, this is not the place to ask 'What is best x' questions. Please see [ask]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Altough this is not the place for asking what is the best, i'd advise you to have a look at OpenCV(https://opencv.org/) or its Java-Implementation JavaCV (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, JMF is seriously old and has not been updated in a long, long time.  It is also limited in that it only supports video4Linux version 1, not version 2 that means most modern webcams are not supported.

An alternative is FMJ (Freedom for Media in Java).  This is mostly API compatible with JMF so a good replacement.

http://fmj-sf.net/

https://github.com/Metaswitch/fmj

https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmj/

Comment: Thanks for that.  Looking into FMJ, OpenCV (java bindings) and VLC 64Bit.

Comment: FYI - FMJ is no longer being maintained.